# unable to access JSON array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a JSON file and I'm trying to access the array in it.

The JSON file looks like:

```
{
 "cars": [{
                    "name": "BMW",
                    "icons": [["front.png", "back.png", "B3"],
                              ["front_red", "back_red", "C4"]
                             ]
           }]
}
```

//cars is an array of dictionaries, I just mentioned one in the snippet.

I get the JSON data as:

```
func loadJSONData(){

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testJSON", ofType: "json")
        {
            if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile : path)
            {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                    {
                        self.testJSONData = (jsonResult["cars"] as? Array)! 
                        //self.testJSONData = (jsonResult["cars"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>)!    //also tried this
                    }

                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

testJSONData is declared as an array:

```
var testJSONData = [] as [Dictionary<String, Any>]
```

and the error occurs when trying to get the "icons" array from the JSON.

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name like BMW")
let filteredArray :Array = testJSONData.filter() { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
let carData: Dictionary = filteredArray[0] as Dictionary<String, Any>
let carIcons: Array = carData["icons"] as! Array //error at this line
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Array<_>' to specified type 'Array'

Can someone please show me where I'm doing wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: You need to give the array a type: `jsonResult["cars"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` or `jsonResult["cars"] as? [[String : Any]]`.

Comment: It might be unrelated directly to the question, but why don't use `Codeable`?

Comment: @keithbhunter I got the same error after giving the array type

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks for the hint, I will surely look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a generic type in Swift, so when you want to declare an array variable, you always need to specific what type of elements the `Array` is holding. There's no such type as `Array` without specifying its `Element` type.

Also, there's no need for type annotations in Swift, the compiler can infer the types for you and you are explicitly telling the compiler the type by casting anyways.

`carIcons` should be of type `Array<Array<String>>` or as a shorthand `[[String]]`

```
let carIcons = carData["icons"] as! [[String]]
```

Some general comments about your code: don't use old Foundation types, such as `NSData` in Swift when they have native Swift equivalents. Also don't do force unwrapping of safe casted types, that makes no sense. Either handle the casting **and** unwrapping safely or simply force cast if you know the cast will succeed for sure. `.mutableContainers` have no effect in Swift, so don't use it. There's no need to cast `error` to `NSError` in a catch block, Swift has its own `Error` type.

```
func loadJSONData(){
    if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testJSON", withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOfFile: fileURL)
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String:Any], let cars = jsonResult["cars"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.testJSONData = cars
            } else {
                print("Unexpected JSON format")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you are using Swift 4, the best solution would be using the type safe `Codable` protocol and `JSONDecoder` instead of `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: The type of `icons` is actually `[[String]]`

Comment: @vadian you're absolutely right, thanks for the heads up, updated my answer